# Infopath 2010 download source

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, infopath

The organization that I work for wants to setup a dev environment of what we are working with now. while setting up old SharePoint projects which runs on VS 2010 needs Infopath 2010. I need Microsoft download source for infopath 2010 else dlls also work if someone is still using 2010 infopath.

thanks in advance..

Comment: I would not trust any download-links out on the web. Your best bet would be to try get a office 2010 license somehow. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/where-is-the-infopath-2010-download-link/27c07cf2-fdd2-4839-8ae0-df43bdbc0c7b

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft provides downloads of all old version of software they have released. If you have visual studio subscription you can download version by yourself. Otherwise your organisation needs to provide you with a licensed product.